# Polars: Nesting `over` calls

Tags: python, dataframe, window-functions, python-polars

**Context.** I have written a function that computes the mean of all elements in a column except the elements in the current group.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
    "value": [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5],
})

def sum_excl_group(val_exp: pl.Expr, group_expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return val_exp.sum() - val_exp.sum().over(group_expr)

def count_non_null_excl_group(val_exp: pl.Expr, group_expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return val_exp.is_not_null().sum() - val_exp.is_not_null().sum().over(group_expr)

def mean_excl_group(val_exp: pl.Expr, group_expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return sum_excl_group(val_exp,group_expr) / count_non_null_excl_group(val_exp, group_expr)

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        mean_excl_group(pl.col("value"), pl.col("group")).alias("mean_excl_group"),
    )
)
```

This gives the expected result.

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────┬───────┬─────────────────┐
│ group ┆ value ┆ mean_excl_group │
│ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---             │
│ str   ┆ i64   ┆ f64             │
╞═══════╪═══════╪═════════════════╡
│ A     ┆ 1     ┆ 3.5             │
│ A     ┆ 3     ┆ 3.5             │
│ B     ┆ 2     ┆ 3.0             │
│ B     ┆ 4     ┆ 3.0             │
│ C     ┆ 3     ┆ 2.5             │
│ C     ┆ 5     ┆ 2.5             │
└───────┴───────┴─────────────────┘
```

---

**Problem.** Now, I am facing the issue that I would like to run this function *within* an `over` context to obtain the mean of all elements in a group, except the elements in the current subgroup.

I would've expected the following to work.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "group": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
    "subgroup": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
    "value": [1, 3, 2, 4, 3, 5],
})

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        mean_excl_group(pl.col("value"), pl.col("subgroup")).over("group").alias("mean_excl_group"),
    )
)
```

but get an `InvalidOperationError`

```
InvalidOperationError: window expression not allowed in aggregation
```

---

**Attempt.** For now, I have "solved" this issue by avoiding the nested `over` calls.

```
def sum_excl_group(val_exp: pl.Expr, coarse_group_expr: pl.Expr, fine_group_expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return val_exp.sum().over(coarse_group_expr) - val_exp.sum().over(fine_group_expr)

def count_non_null_excl_group(val_exp: pl.Expr, coarse_group_expr: pl.Expr, fine_group_expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return val_exp.is_not_null().sum().over(coarse_group_expr) - val_exp.is_not_null().sum().over(fine_group_expr)

def mean_excl_group(val_exp: pl.Expr, coarse_group_expr: pl.Expr, fine_group_expr: pl.Expr) -> pl.Expr:
    return sum_excl_group(val_exp, coarse_group_expr, fine_group_expr) / count_non_null_excl_group(val_exp, coarse_group_expr, fine_group_expr)

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        mean_excl_group(pl.col("value"), pl.col("group"), pl.col("subgroup")).alias("mean_excl_group"),
    )
)
```

This gives the expected result.

```
shape: (6, 4)
┌───────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────────┐
│ group ┆ subgroup ┆ value ┆ mean_excl_group │
│ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---             │
│ str   ┆ str      ┆ i64   ┆ f64             │
╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════════╡
│ A     ┆ a        ┆ 1     ┆ 3.0             │
│ A     ┆ b        ┆ 3     ┆ 1.0             │
│ B     ┆ c        ┆ 2     ┆ 4.0             │
│ B     ┆ d        ┆ 4     ┆ 2.0             │
│ C     ┆ e        ┆ 3     ┆ 5.0             │
│ C     ┆ f        ┆ 5     ┆ 3.0             │
└───────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────────┘
```

However, this requires me to pass both granularities to all functions making the code more bloated than (I hope) it needs to be. Is there a cleaner more polaric way to solve the problem of nested `over` calls?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not what you're after, but your example made me think of this.

Create a group for "all rows" to make the pattern repeatable.

```py
def over_exclude(self, *over):
    if len(over) == 1:
        over = [True, *over]
    return self.over(over[0]) - self.over(over)
    
pl.Expr.over_exclude = over_exclude
```

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("value").sum().over_exclude("group")
      / pl.col("value").is_not_null().sum().over_exclude("group")
)

# shape: (6, 3)
# ┌───────┬──────────┬───────┐
# │ group ┆ subgroup ┆ value │
# │ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
# │ str   ┆ str      ┆ f64   │
# ╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════╡
# │ A     ┆ a        ┆ 3.5   │
# │ A     ┆ b        ┆ 3.5   │
# │ B     ┆ c        ┆ 3.0   │
# │ B     ┆ d        ┆ 3.0   │
# │ C     ┆ e        ┆ 2.5   │
# │ C     ┆ f        ┆ 2.5   │
# └───────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("value").sum().over_exclude("group", "subgroup")
      / pl.col("value").is_not_null().sum().over_exclude("group", "subgroup")
)

# shape: (6, 3)
# ┌───────┬──────────┬───────┐
# │ group ┆ subgroup ┆ value │
# │ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
# │ str   ┆ str      ┆ f64   │
# ╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════╡
# │ A     ┆ a        ┆ 3.0   │
# │ A     ┆ b        ┆ 1.0   │
# │ B     ┆ c        ┆ 4.0   │
# │ B     ┆ d        ┆ 2.0   │
# │ C     ┆ e        ┆ 5.0   │
# │ C     ┆ f        ┆ 3.0   │
# └───────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

Perhaps there's some neat way to avoid the need to repeat the `.over_exclude`

---

#### Down a rabbit hole.

This is straying further off-topic but just an update as I found it rather interesting.

It turns out you can dump and load expressions to/from JSON.

```py
>>> pl.lit(1).add(1).meta.serialize()
'{"BinaryExpr":{"left":{"Literal":{"Int32":1}},"op":"Plus","right":{"Literal":{"Int32":1}}}}'
```

Meaning you can also modify them:

```py
import json

node = json.loads(pl.lit(1).add(1).meta.serialize())
node["BinaryExpr"]["left"] = {"Alias":[{"Literal":{"Float64":42}},"hi"]}

pl.select(pl.Expr.from_json(json.dumps(node)))

# shape: (1, 1)
# ┌──────┐
# │ hi   │
# │ ---  │
# │ f64  │
# ╞══════╡
# │ 43.0 │
# └──────┘
```

So it is actually possible to make `(pl.col("value").sum() / pl.col("value").is_not_null().sum()).over_exclude("group", "subgroup")`  work via "AST transformations".

Not something that's applicable here, but quite fascinating.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a solution, but I did realize that as the nested over doesn't fail until it is evaluated.

```py
>>> mean_excl_group(pl.col("value"), pl.col("subgroup")).over("group")
<polars.expr.expr.Expr object at 0x12d8c6320>
```

It is technically possible to rewrite it at the "AST level" to make your first example work.

```py
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        _rewrite_nested_over(
            mean_excl_group(pl.col("value"), pl.col("subgroup")).over("group").alias("mean_excl_group")
        )
    )
)

# shape: (6, 4)
# ┌───────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────────┐
# │ group ┆ subgroup ┆ value ┆ mean_excl_group │
# │ ---   ┆ ---      ┆ ---   ┆ ---             │
# │ str   ┆ str      ┆ i64   ┆ f64             │
# ╞═══════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════════╡
# │ A     ┆ a        ┆ 1     ┆ 3.0             │
# │ A     ┆ b        ┆ 3     ┆ 1.0             │
# │ B     ┆ c        ┆ 2     ┆ 4.0             │
# │ B     ┆ d        ┆ 4     ┆ 2.0             │
# │ C     ┆ e        ┆ 3     ┆ 5.0             │
# │ C     ┆ f        ┆ 5     ┆ 3.0             │
# └───────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────────┘
```

Is there a reliable pattern to do this for the general case I wonder?

```py
def _rewrite_nested_over(expr):
    node = json.loads(expr.meta.write_json())

    alias = node.get("Alias") 
    
    if alias is not None:
        node, alias = alias
        
    window = node["Window"]
    binary_expr = window["function"]["BinaryExpr"]
    
    left  = binary_expr["left"]
    right = binary_expr["right"]

    new_node = {
        "BinaryExpr": {
            "left": {
                "BinaryExpr": left["BinaryExpr"] | {"left": {"Window": window | {"function": left["BinaryExpr"]["left"]}}}
            },
            "op": binary_expr["op"],
            "right": {
                "BinaryExpr": right["BinaryExpr"] | {"left": {"Window": window | {"function": right["BinaryExpr"]["left"]}}}
            }
        }
    }
    
    new_expr = pl.Expr.from_json(json.dumps(new_node))
    
    if alias is not None:
        new_expr = new_expr.alias(alias)
        
    return new_expr
```

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/6676 seems to be the most recent nested-over issue I can find.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely broadens my (polars) horizon. I'll need some time to look at expressions at the AST level, but looks really cool!

Comment: Btw. I am not accepting an answer atm to encourage more answers, but I really appreciate your continuous input!

Comment: @Hericks Not a problem. Neither of my posts answer the "real question" so should not be accepted. I submitted them incase they sparked ideas/input/conversations from others (as it's rather interesting functionality) and incase someone could improve upon them.